# when view is being created database name is automatically being specified in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

When I try to create a MySQL view, the database is being automatically specified when the view is saved.

*Sample:*

**database.table_name**

Is it my connection problem? or another thing? badly need help on this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Views are created in databases and they differ between different database instances. 
So you have to put database name, otherwise it will use the current database as the database.

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz only occurred with 5 views, but to be exact, it only automatically adds database name when i used this 1 view. I don't know if it was a problem with the table that had been used for the 1st view.